# Problema al realizar logging en python

Tags: python, log

agradezco si alguien pude echarme una mano.
Estoy realizando uno ejercicios de aprendizaje de python, tengo que ingresar un numero para adivinar y el numero de intentos. Tengo que realizar la comprobación de si un usuario mete una letra o un carácter que no sea un integer salte una excepción. Si entra en la excepción debe mostrar un logging indicando que el vamor a ingresar debe de ser entero.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo en el código lo que muestro en la imagen.
Pero cuando lo intento ejecutar me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otra parte me han pedido que muestre la ejecución con la clase logging. Pero al intentar mostrar el resultado de la opercion en caso de que se adivine el numero o sea erroneo.
Si es erroneo, debe de indicar un mensaje de que es erroneo y mostrar el numero de intentos que queda, y si se acierta el numero, mostrar una lista de intentos que se han introducido antes de acertar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ingresar el numero correcto me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos mensajes de ejecución que contienen una lista o un integer ¿Se podrian mostrar mediante la clase logging? o solamente mediante print.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, sé que te has currado las imágenes, pero ¿podrías quitarlas y añadir el texto? Si no quieres que salga información tuya cámbialo por otra cosa pero si pones el texto mejor porque así ayudas a que sea más fácil encontrar tu pregunta en un futuro ya que el buscador no puede encontrar el texto en una imagen. Un saludo.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu